# Code behide VB.connection string?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, connection-string, mysql-workbench

I am currently developing a webpage using `ASP.NET` with `VB` as back end. But I am facing a problem. I don't know how to make a database connection to connect with `MYSQL WORKBENCH`. I just wrote the connection but it just code for `SQL server`.

This is my sample code for connection but it for `sql server`. I just want code for `mySQL` workbench.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

  Partial Class Request
      Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

      Dim con As New SqlConnection
      Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      txt1.Focus()
      txt2.Focus()
      txt3.Focus()
      txt4.Focus()
      txt5.Focus()
      txt6.Focus()
      txt7.Focus()
      ddl1.Focus()
      ddl2.Focus()
      ddl3.Focus()
      ddl4.Focus()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnsubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsubmit.Click
    con.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;"

    con.Open()

    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cr_record (Emplid, Nama, date, DeptDesc, email, Change, reasonchange,problem,priority,reasondescription,systemrequest) VALUES  (@Emplid, @Nama, @date, @DeptDesc, @email, @Change, @reasonchange,@problem,@priority,@reasondescription,@systemrequest)"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emplid", ddl1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nama", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", txt5.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptDesc", txt2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txt4.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Change", ddl2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reasonchange", txt6.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problem", ddl3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priority", rbl1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reasondescription", txt7.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@systemrequest", ddl4.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()

    MsgBox("Added Successfully")
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 2):

You will need to download and reference the **MySQL .NET Connector** http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/. You will then use the `System.Data.MySqlClient` namespace and replace your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` with `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand`

Comment: so i want to ask you how about the open connection and close connection it that right.? Sorry i dont get it. i really dont know how to connect database. i just learn from google..then when i writedown myself it seem like i using wrong connection..please help me..give example code for that..i really appreciate it. im student just bignner just learn for my self to be become like you all. tq @equisde

Comment: Here's a good  step-by-step guide on how to use VB.NET to connect to MySQL database. Hope this help. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/115753-use-vbnet-to-connect-to-mysql/

Comment: I remember doing this for a utility program I wrote in vb.net to quickly generate database structures and test data for freelance work.. the MySQL .net driver worked great... My only hiccup was that not all webhosts allow whitelisting of IPs to their MySQL server instances.